# django website: As i logged out, but click on the browser backspace arrow, it display the former webpage

Tags: python, django, web, logout

The web backend is written in django.
As i logged out, but click on the browser backspace arrow, it display the former webpage;
code:

```
def safe_exit(request):
    #print request
    if 'uname' in request.session and 'uid' in request.session:
        del request.session['uname']
        del request.session['uid']
        del request.session['logged_in']
    #return render_to_response('reader/login.html',{})
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

what i want is : it should redirect to the login page. How to achieve this, i have tried to use ajax to get the user's login status, but it's work, because after i click on the backspace arrow, i use firebug to listen on the network, it didn't send any http request at all.

Comment: Use a decorator to protect your views or a middleware.

Comment: thanks, but i think it'll not work. BC, after i click backspace button,it didn't render to any urls at all. so the decorator will not work.

Comment: The previous page is being cached by the browser. Have you explicitly set any caching and is it a page requiring an authenticated user?

Comment: I didn't set the cache policy, and the page needs an authenticated user, so that if a user logout he(she) should relogin to proceed.

Comment: You can try to use never_cache decorator. from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def myview(request):

Comment: thanks,Aldarund, it worked! but it also display the former webpage in less than 1s, and then render to the login webpage.

Comment: and another confusion, if i want all views to not get cached, should i add @never_cache decorator on all view functions? or exists a much more simple way to achieve this?

Comment: It looks as though the AJAX check you implemented is redirecting to the login page which could mean the page isn't properly protected. Are you using the Django authentication system (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) or have you implemented your own? If you are using the Django authentication system do you call [logout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out) when logging out?

Comment: thanks AdrewS, i implemented the auth in my own, so i didn't use the django defaule auth system.and i temporily resolved it by add the meta into html file to let browser not cache the webpage, so the backspace button will direct to login page. But i think this is not the best solution, if the user didn't logged out, then it will spend much more time to load resources from server.Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I would strongly advise using the default Django authentication system. It's customisable and extensible should it fall short of your requirements (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/). The advantage is it's extensively tested, integrated with other parts of Django and is typically used by third party apps. I'd also look at using a cache backend for parts of protected pages that shouldn't be cached but are costly on database queries.